# automatic resize the textbox as per data in the database

Tags: php, mysql, html

i am fetching data from mysql database and out of those fetching data-- 4 fields

are in the textbox.
so i want to resize the rows as per the total record present in the database.
i have used this code----

```
 <tr  bgcolor="#DFEFFF">

<td align="left" style="vertical-align:top;"><h3>Description</h3></td>

 <td align="left"><textarea name="feature" id="features" rows="5" cols="74" 

disabled style="background-color:#DFEFFF; border:none; color:#000; font-

family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;"><?php echo $results['des'];?

></textarea></td>

 </tr>
```

if i am using auto in rows = "auto"   , then even its not working.
plz help in the auto display in the textarea.

I want if admin use copy paste method to insert the data than at the front end, the textarea will auto resize and contain all the data present in the database.

I am still for looking for this answer. plz reply ..

Answer (score 3):

A better solution should be not to worry about it on your server at all.

Use javascript to set the size of textarea as per data in the textarea.

You might like this jquery plugin to [autoresize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
<textarea name="feature" rows="<?php echo $numRows; ?>" ...>
```

Having first set `$numRows` according to the database extension you are using.

E.g.

`$numRows = $stmt->rowCount()` for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Or:

`$result->num_row` for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Comment: Have you defined a `$numRows` variable according to the Database extension you are using?

Comment: but if user enter the  data using copy paste than all the data considered as 1 line than it show only 1 line.

Comment: Ah, in which case I would go for the other answer.